# pySpark: Get executor id

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How can I get the executor id when running pySpark code? I am aware that with scala I can use `SparkEnv.get().executorId()`, but I cannot find the equivalent when using pySpark.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [REST API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api) to query the executors, I have used it in [pySparkUtils](https://github.com/boazmohar/pySparkUtils) to find the [executor IPs](https://github.com/boazmohar/pySparkUtils/blob/405f15985fe2ba08cdd3305556cd584f1b3f66de/pySparkUtils/utils.py#L21)

Boaz

Answer (score -1):

The Spark UI will give you access to the executor id's as well as their individual performance metrics.